# Possible number of varieties in family over finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field.

Let $V$ be a smooth proper variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Consider the isomorphism classes of smooth proper varieties that can be put in a common proper flat family with $V$. There may be finitely or infinitely many. For example if $V$ is one-dimensional there's finitely many.

Given a natural number $n$ can we always find $V$ such that the number is finite and equal to $n$?

Weaker questions: can we get $2$ in this way? Can we get a subset of positive Dirichlet density?

Comment: Do you allow V to be, for instance, the union of two points?

Comment: @Asvin we require varieties to be geometrically connected

Comment: I find the question a bit difficult to parse. Could you try rephrasing it by breaking up the long sentence?

Comment: @DanielLoughran I edited